# Transfer a fixed value in all linkes of my website in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a **login.aspx** page .after login I want to add the username to **url**, but the important part is that I want to fix the username in my url.

Suppose after login to website I redirect to a **main.aspx** page.

The main page has for example 3 links. I don't wan to add the username to these 3 links manually. I want, after each click on these 3 links the **username** values add to url automatically.

```
   response.redirect("x.aspx?id="+id.tostring());
```

How can I do that?

Best regards.

ASP.NET

Comment: can i use config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a custom [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
public class UserUrlRewriteModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.context_BeginRequest);
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        var user = context.User;
        if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?id=" + user.Name);
    }

    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

For this to work, you will need to register it in your `web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="UserUrlRewriteModule" type="UserUrlRewriteModule" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i should use this class in all pages ?

Comment: @user3216600 no you register the handler in the web.config and it will automatically be called for every request.

Comment: I create a class with "MyHttpModule " name but i got this error :Error 19 'samta.adminPortal.Company.MyHttpModule' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.IHttpModule.Dispose()'

Comment: After login i want  to send a id to this class .how should i do that?

Comment: @user3216600 see update to fix the error you are seeing (forgot `IHttpModule` had the `Dispose` method). As for your other question, my example is assuming you are leveraging the ASP.NET Membership provider for your login logic - if you aren't then your best shout will be to add the `id` to the `Session` and check for that value in your HttpModule.

Comment: Thank you .i did that but i got this error :HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error.after running

Comment: @user3216600 An internal server error is basically an unhandled exception, read the callstack and use the debugger to inspect what's going on...

Comment: it doesn't allow me to trace it but in the error i found the causes :
    This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpModules section.

Comment: the problem is because of web.config

Comment: If you see the text "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined", this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4. If you are running WebMatrix, to resolve this problem, go to the Settings node to set the .NET Framework version to ".NET 2". You can also remove the extra sections from the web.config file.

Comment: It means i should change my dot net to version 2?